# how to get redux state to update immediately for a useeffect call?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

im abit lost in terms of using redux. what im trying to do is on useeffect, call my get API action, then call a reducer to set the redux state. However, the value of the redux state is being called when the initial value is still null. is there a way to work around this?

the solutions ive tried are to use a local state, which works perfectly with the following code

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("/inventory/get")      
      setRowData(res.data.data)
    }
    fetchData()

}, []);
```

now this axios.get is actually a copy of my redux action.

when i try to instead dispatch the get action, the state is not updated immediately along with it. here is the code when i try to use dispatch

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res =  dispatch(getInventory())
      console.log(res)
    }
    setRowData(props.inventory.inventory)
     
    // setRowData(props.inventory)
}, []);
```

is there a proper way to do this with redux? ive searched online to no avail, i dont know if i might have missed anything or if this is a repeat question, any references or advice would help.

this is the whole code of the page and redux

page

```
   function InventoryData(props){
    const dispatch = new useDispatch()
    const gridRef = useRef();
    const [rowData,setRowData] = useState(props.inventory.inventory);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          const res =  dispatch(getInventory())
          console.log(res)
        }
        setRowData(props.inventory.inventory)
         
        // setRowData(props.inventory)
    }, []);  
    
    const [columnDefs] = useState([
        { field: 'id', width: 100},
        { field: 'product_category' },
        { field: 'product_cost'},
        { field: 'product_desc'},
        { field: 'product_name'},
        { field: 'product_price'},

    ])
    const onFirstDataRendered = useCallback((params) => {
        gridRef.current.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
      }, []);
      return(
            <div>
        <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height: 650, width: '100%'}}>
        <AgGridReact
        ref={gridRef}
            onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered}
            rowData={rowData}
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
            pagination={true}

            >
        </AgGridReact>
            </div>
        <button onClick={(e)=>{console.log(props.data)}}>asf</button>
    </div>
      )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    inventory: state.inventory
  })
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(InventoryData)
```

redux

```
export const inventorySlice = createSlice({
  name: "inventory",
  initialState: {
    inventory: [
        
    ],
  },
  reducers: {
    setInventory: (state,action)=>{
      state.inventory = action.payload.data
    }
  },
});

export const { setInventory,
             } = inventorySlice.actions;

export default inventorySlice.reducer;
export const getInventory = ()=>{
    return async dispatch =>{
      try{
          const res = await axios.get("/inventory/get")
          // console.log(res.data.data)
        await dispatch(setInventory(res.data))
        return res.data
    }catch(err){
  
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: the scenario is when the page refreshes btw, thats why im using useeffect

Answer (score 0):

god, so apparently i missed an important detail of useEffect that watches state changes on rerender. therefore i came up with this and it worked. But the question still remains, is this the right way?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
     
    }
    dispatch(getInventory())     
    setRowData(props.inventory.inventory)
    // setRowData(props.inventory)
}, [props.inventory.inventory]);
```